# Getting the value inside specific quotes with preg_match()

Tags: regex, wordpress, preg-match

I am trying to get the value inside specific quotes from Wordpress content string. I managed to get content but I couldn't use the correct preg_match function.

Example content is:

```
[vc_single_image image="1667" img_size="full" alignment="center" onclick="img_link_large" css_animation="fadeIn"]
```

From this string, I am trying to get the value "1667" by using preg_match function.

I have this code right now:

```
$regex = '/"([^"]+)"/';
$output = preg_match($regex, $post->post_content, $matches);
$first_img_id = trim($matches[0][21], '"');
```

When I echo out this code, it is working properly. But I am getting the value by checking only quotes. If I add more strings with quotes, then my code will not work properly. Therefore, I want to get the image id with **"image="** part. How should I change my regex and matches array indexes?

Comment: Are you trying to get 1+ digits after `image="`? `$regex = '/(?:\s|\[)image="\K\d+/';`?

Comment: For example, in this situation, I want to get "1667" which means just the content of "image=" part.

Comment: Have you tried `$regex = '/(?:\s|\[)image="\K\d+/';`? Try also `$regex = '/(?:\s|\[)image="\K[^"]+/';`

Comment: When I use online regex tester, it shows that there is a match. After that how do I get the value for that match? For example, if I write `echo $matches[1]`, does it give me the result? But it seems that this regex is going to work because online regex tester found the value that I want.

Comment: You need to get it via `$match[0]` after `preg_match($rx, $s, $matches)`.

Comment: I added an answer with detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is a set of key-value pairs inside square brackets. You may match any specific key value by using a `preg_match` function with a regex like

```
"~[\s[]$key=\"\K[^\"]*~"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4rIx8m/1) for the current scenario with `image`.

The `[\s[]` matches either a whitespace, or `[` char, that is, it matches the left boundary of the key. `$key` is a variable that should not contain non-word chars, and in real life, keys usually consist of word chars. `="` matches an equal sign and a quote after it, but the `\K` *match reset operator* clears the match value, and only the text that is matched by `[^"]*` (zero or more chars other than `"`) gets put into the match memory buffer, and that is what you get by accessing the first item in the resulting `$matches` array.

See the [online PHP demo](https://ideone.com/fns9hm):

```
$key="image";
$regex = "~[\s[]$key=\"\K[^\"]*~";
$content='[vc_single_image image="1667" img_size="full" alignment="center" onclick="img_link_large" css_animation="fadeIn"]';
if (preg_match($regex, $content, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[0];
}
```

Output: `1667`

Comment: Thank you! This is working pretty good and the explanation is also very clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

For the records, you could get all key/value pairs immediately with

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)
[^][]*?\K
(?P<key>\w+)="(?P<value>\w+)"
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ib47UZ/2/).

Comment: I am sorry, I am a bit confused now because of my lack of knowledge about this. How should I change the code right now and how can I get the value by using key/value pairs?

Answer (score 0):

It might be an option to first use  [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove the `[` and `]` from the beginning and end from the string and use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) using a whitespace as the delimiter.

Then you could loop the array from explode and use a regex like for example [`^image="(\d+)"$`](https://regex101.com/r/MjIwsd/1/) to match `image="1667"`in the loop.

If it matches, capturing group 1 `(\d+)` will contain your value

`^image="(\d+)"$` will match:

- `^` Assert position at the start of the string
- `image="` Match literally
- `(\d+)` Match one or more digits in a capturing group
- `"` Match literally
- `$` Assert position at the end of the string

[Demo php](https://3v4l.org/eUeVJ)